# Divs not in the right position when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I got 6 divs of which they each have an image and a button (javascript). When I click on a button of one of the divs, another div will show on the exact same place of the button of the div you clicked. When I click on all buttons separate, there is no problem. But when I click by example 'auto 2' and 'auto 3', 'auto 3" will show on the right side of the screen, not on the place where it will show when you click on the button separate. I got also this problem with 'auto 4,5 and 6. I dont got this problem with the first div 'auto 1' because its has an absolute position. When I used an absolute position on the other divs i couldnt position them properly. I think the problem has to do something with the fact that a div has a block display and that by example 'auto 2' pushes 'auto 3" to the side because it is wider than it looks.

PS. srry for my bad english and I used and internal javascript with  tags because an external document like .js doesnt work for me for some reason

Thanks in advance!

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #234aa6;
}

.auto{
    padding-top: 4em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}

.auto h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.auto img{
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

.auto button{
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.auto button:hover{
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color: #011b57;
}

.container {
    text-align: center; 
}

.auto:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear:left;
}

.wrapper input{
    padding: 20px 100px 20px 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10em;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}

.select1{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.select1 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.bg{
    width: 570.83px;
    height: 325px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding-top: 3.5em;
}

.select2{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 39.5em;
    bottom: 65.5em;
}

.select2 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.select3{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 79em;
    bottom: 65.5em;
}

.select3 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.select4{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0.25em;
    bottom: 32.9em;
}

.select4 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.select5{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 39.5em;
    bottom: 32.9em;
}

.select5 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}

.select6{
    padding-top: 3.8em;
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    left: 79em;
    bottom: 32.9em;
}

.select6 h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sleutelkast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="autolijst">

    <div class="auto">
        <h1>Auto 1</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button1">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="auto" id="auto">
        <h1>Auto 2</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button2">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="auto" id="auto">
        <h1>Auto 3</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button3">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="auto" id="auto">
        <h1>Auto 4</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button4">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="auto" id="auto">
        <h1>Auto 5</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button5">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="auto" id="auto">
        <h1>Auto 6</h1>
        <img src="https://topgear.nl/app/uploads/2019/07/bmw-x6-m-2019.jpg">
        <div class="container">
            <button id="button6">SELECTEER</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="selectlijst">

    <div class="select1" id="select1">
        <h1>Auto 1</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 1
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select2" id="select2">
        <h1>Auto 2</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 2
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select3" id="select3">
        <h1>Auto 3</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 3
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select4" id="select4">
        <h1>Auto 4</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 4
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select5" id="select5">
        <h1>Auto 5</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 5
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="select6" id="select6">
        <h1>Auto 6</h1>
    <div class="bg" id="bg">
         Sleutel 6
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select1").hide();
    $("#button1").click(function(){
    if($(".select1").is(':visible')){
       $(".select1").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select1").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select2").hide();
    $("#button2").click(function(){
    if($(".select2").is(':visible')){
       $(".select2").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select2").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select3").hide();
    $("#button3").click(function(){
    if($(".select3").is(':visible')){
       $(".select3").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select3").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select4").hide();
    $("#button4").click(function(){
    if($(".select4").is(':visible')){
       $(".select4").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select4").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select5").hide();
    $("#button5").click(function(){
    if($(".select5").is(':visible')){
       $(".select5").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select5").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select6").hide();
    $("#button6").click(function(){
    if($(".select6").is(':visible')){
       $(".select6").slideUp(100);
       }
       else
       {
       $(".select6").slideDown(100);
       }
    });
    });



</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You had a bad structure design of HTML markup. Each item should be wrapped into a same container with its covered div.

Comment: Will that small adjustment fix everything?